# Return not returing durning while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to do the The Collatz Sequence found at the bottom the page in the link below. But I dont know why my return value inst returning? Thanks.

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/

Im not getting an error. If the user inputs the value 10.  the Elif line runs and prints out 5, as it should. But then the program exits the loop.

```
userNum = int(input("Please enter a number, any number!"))
def collatz(number):  
    while True:
        if number ==  1:
            print("Of course 1 works....")
            break
        elif number % 2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
            return number
        else:
            print(3 * number + 1)
            return number

collatz(userNum)
```

Comment: Please state what error / issue your are getting specifically

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `While True:` is a syntax error.

Comment: In place Capital W write small w

Comment: I replaced the w and still no luck.  Im not getting an error. If the user inputs the value 10. the Elif line runs and prints out 5, as it should. But then the program exits the loop.

Comment: _"But then the program exits the loop."_ Yes, that's what happens when a `return` executes; it immediately terminates the function it's in, whether it's inside a loop or not. So really your question isn't "why isn't this returning when it should return?", but "why is this returning when I don't want it to?"

Answer (score 0):

If a function is returning a value, you will have to save it or print it to show the value.

Try

Python 3+
print(collatz(userNum))

Python 2
print collatz(userNum)

Answer (score 0):

`While True` will return a syntax error.

You need to make the `W` lower-case.

`while True` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your function there is only one way the function doesn't return anything:
If the parameter number is 1.
In this case python will break out of your loop and then comes to the end of the function. 
Perhaps you wanted to use continue instead of break, which will stay in loop or better: just remove break.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is this.

```
userNum = int(input("Please enter a number, any number!"))
def collatz(number):  
    while True:
        if number ==  1:
            return number
        elif number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1

collatz(userNum)
print("It worked! Collatz Conjecture must be true!")
```

Although, mathematics in their current form might not be ready to tell you if that will always terminate.